# Quick question about CircuitPython simpleio.tone function

Tags: python, list, parameters, adafruit-circuitpython

With simpleio.tone(board, frequency, duration=), I know how to iterate through a list of frequencies in the frequency parameter using a for loop. How would I do this for the duration parameter as well? I want to play a song with the piezo buzzer and I need different frequencies to play for different durations.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Dictionaries**

You could create a dictionary to store the frequency as the key and the duration as its value. This means that you can then iterate over the dictionary and play the frequency for the amount of time specified by the duration.

```
# The key is the frequency and the value is the duration
data = {"124hz": 10, "125hz": 1, "126hz": 5}
for sound, duration in data.items():
  # Play sound for duration.
  print("Playing {} for {}s".format(sound, duration))
```

The output of the above code would look like this.

```
Playing 124hz for 10s
Playing 125hz for 1s
Playing 126hz for 5s
```

Instead of have it outputting these as print statements, you would just have to use methods within the simpleio module to send the data to the piezo buzzer to make the sound

Comment: That dictionary only allows a frequency to appear once. It's also dependent on whether dictionaries are ordered in the Python implementation being used. I would recommend a list of tuples: `data = [(440, 10), (494, 1), (523, 5), (440, 6)]` and change the loop to `for sound, duration in data:`. The print statement would provide the frequency unit `...{}hz...` so the value could be used directly in the `tone` call.